# Gulp task not running properly

Tags: node.js, gulp

A little context:
I am following this tutorial: and at time 23:20 we have created a gulpfile.js that will take a scss file and convert it to css. Since I needed to modify the code to Gulp 4, here is my code:

```
'use strict';

//Dependencies
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var changed = require('gulp-changed');



////////////////////
// - SCSS/CSS
////////////////////

var SCSS_SRC = '.src/Assets/Assets/*.scss';
var SCSS_DEST = './src/Assets/css';

//Compile SCSS
gulp.task('compile_scss', gulp.series(function(){
  gulp.src(SCSS_SRC)
  .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
  .pipe(minifyCSS())
  .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
  .pipe(changed(SCSS_DEST))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(SCSS_DEST));
}));

//Detect changes in SCSS
gulp.task('watch_scss', gulp.series(function(){
  gulp.watch(SCSS_SRC, gulp.series(['compile_scss']))
}));


//Run tasks
gulp.task('default', gulp.series(['watch_scss']));
```

What were you expecting to happen?
I am expecting it to create a css file in the appropriate path.

What actually happened?
No css file created

What version of gulp are you using?
version 4
What versions of npm and node are you using?
npm: 6.4.1
Node: v10.15.1

When I run the gulp command in my project, I get the following:

````
[21:35:41] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\reactTutorial\personal-website\src\gulpfile.js
[21:35:41] Starting 'default'...
[21:35:41] Starting 'watch_scss'...
[21:35:41] Starting '<anonymous>'...```

I assume its running right but it doesnt seem like its actually able to access the 'compile_scss'
````

Answer (score 0):

You're very close. The `SCSS_SRC` glob is missing a forward slash in the beginning and should become:

```js
var SCSS_SRC = './src/Assets/Assets/*.scss';
```

That is enough to make it work. However, there are some other improvements that you could make. Some uses of `gulp.series` are redundant, although not strictly wrong. Your `compile_scss` task for example can be simplified to:

```js
gulp.task('compile_scss', function() {
  return gulp.src(SCSS_SRC)
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(changed(SCSS_DEST))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(SCSS_DEST));
});
```

Note that I added a return statement to signal completion of the task to gulp.

When listing tasks in `gulp.series`, you can also lose the brackets:

```js
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('watch_scss'));
```

Putting it all together, you get:

```js
'use strict';

//Dependencies
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var changed = require('gulp-changed');

////////////////////
// - SCSS/CSS
////////////////////

var SCSS_SRC = './src/Assets/Assets/*.scss';
var SCSS_DEST = './src/Assets/css';

//Compile SCSS
gulp.task('compile_scss', function() {
  return gulp.src(SCSS_SRC)
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(changed(SCSS_DEST))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(SCSS_DEST));
});

//Detect changes in SCSS
gulp.task('watch_scss', function() {
  gulp.watch(SCSS_SRC, gulp.series('compile_scss'));
});

//Run tasks
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('watch_scss'));
```